# use state if i'm using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

if I'm using redux and redux saga to manage state but a lot of times I wanna do API request for something and I need the result only at this component is it ok to just use state? 
or this considered a bad practice because the idea behind redux is that all the states should be in one place

Comment: it depends.....

Comment: @Tomasz so if the state is not and will not be used at another component its find to do it using state right?

Comment: actually, if I used redux I need to reset the values on unmounting

Comment: Then probably you should do it in the state. Just remember that when the async action completes and executes callback with `this.setState` you may try to execute an update on already unmounted component!

Comment: @Tomasz its visual indicator its ok thanks man

Comment: sure, I posted my comment as an answer. If you feel like I helped feel free to upvote it ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is fine to do it in certain situations. However, you need to be aware of a situation when the request is pending and the user already navigated to a different page of your app. When a request comes back it will try to do `this.setState` on unmounted component!

So I think is that you should trust your instincts on this one :)

You probably have already seen it, but I will share it anyway. [You might not need redux.](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367)